# Single Binary Perceptron in Neural Network

Tags: neural-network

a AND b 
Above boolean function we can implemented by single layer perceptron and we can show that by drawing in 2D space.

(a AND b AND c) OR d
above boolean function also can implemented by single layer perceptron. But how can we prove it?

Comment: Try this link, it has quite good descriptions of perceptrons and simple operations for single layers. http://toritris.weebly.com/perceptron-2-logical-operations.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having spent several years in "normal" software engineering my neural network knowledge is a little hazy, but I'll have a go at an answer. Basically a single layer perceptron is able to make a linear decision, so if you picture a 2D graph of the possible outputs and draw a line down the middle then the single layer perceptron is able to distinguish between outputs on either side of the line. If you can prove that such a linear decision boundary exists for your problem then it is possible to do this with a single layer perceptron. Anything more complicated will require more layers.